# export data with jqgrid to pdf excel

Tags: jqgrid, struts2-jquery

i'm showing data with jquery struts grid and i'm looking for a functionality that
allows to export data to pdf & excel.

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable"
        caption="Editer Eleves"
        dataType="json"
        width="755"
        href="%{remoteurl}"
        pager="true"
        gridModel="gridModel"
        rowList="5,10,15,20"
        rowNum="5"
        rownumbers="true"
        multiselect="true"
        navigator="true"
        navigatorEdit="true"
        editurl="%{editurl}"        
    >
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveId" title="Eleve Id" formatter="integer" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveNom" index="eleveNom" title="Eleve Nom" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="true"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="elevePrenom" index="elevePrenom" title="Eleve Prenom" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveCne" index="eleveCne" title="Eleve Cne" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveAdresse" index="eleveAdresse" title="Eleve Adresse" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="eleveDatenaissance" index="eleveDatenaissance" title="Datenaissance" editable="true" edittype="date" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="anneEnregistrement" index="anneEnregistrement" title="Anne Enregistrement" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="membreClub" index="membreClub" title="Membre Club" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>
    <sjg:gridColumn name="id_classe" index="id_classe" title="classe" editable="true" edittype="text" sortable="false"/>

</sjg:grid>
```

is there a functionnality or should i develop it.any help please!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the programming language that you used.
In PHP, I have to make the functionality using PHPExcel.

If you using the paid version of Jqgrid, there is already have a function to print to PDF or excel file.

Comment: @djoStack: may be this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873088/how-to-implement-export-to-excel-functionality-in-java-struts2). I'm not sure how to implement in struts2. However, I think it some logic. In PHP, I populate the row data first before write to excel work sheet. Or you can requery from DB if you want.